# Tweepy StreamListener ConnectionError

Tags: python, twitter, python-requests, tweepy

Language version:python 2.7.11

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
access_token = "****"
access_token_secret = "****"
consumer_key = "****"
consumer_secret = "****"
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status
if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)
    stream.filter(track=['python', 'javascript', 'ruby'])
```

I get these error information:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stream.twitter.com', port=443): Max retries  
exceeded with url: /1.1/statuses/filter.json?delimited=length (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000002EABD30>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10060] ',))
```

I am a beginner of Python in China,please help me thank you!

Comment: It seems to be a network issue

Comment: I think it may be related to the Chinese can not access twitter.
And I added this code to set proxy:<br>
`proxy = {'http':'http://127.0.0.1:1080', 'https':'https://127.0.0.1:1080'}
 proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler(proxy)
 opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)
 urllib2.install_opener(opener)`
But it doesn't work.

Comment: What are you proxying through?

Comment: I used shadowsocks

Answer (score 0):

I guess it says "max retries". I try again the next day and it works.